# How do I define my own Iterator?

Tags: java, iterator

I've written my own linked-list type data structure, and would like to create an Iterator object that allows me to iterate over the nodes in the list.

Is it possible to directly define my own iterator, or would I first need to convert it to an existing data structure like `LinkedList` and call `iterator()` on that?

Comment: can you show the definition for you data structure? You can just create a new class called `<MyDataType>Iterator` and implement the `Iterator` interface. Then you just have to implement the functions required by the `Iterator` interface. Here is the link to the interface: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define your own Iterator class by implementing the three methods of the [Iterator interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html):

```
boolean hasNext();
E next();
void remove();
```

The last method is optional: you can implement it to just throw an [UnsupportedOperationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html).

The most common strategy is to make the actual class a private member class of your list class. That way it has access to the private bookkeeping data of your class; this is often required to implement an efficient iterator.

Once you do implement an iterator class, it's usually helpful to have the list class implement [Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html). That gives client code a way to obtain an iterator.

Answer (score 3):

You can just create your own class that implements [`Iterator<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html).
It is usually easiest to do that in an inner class.

You would then implement [`Iterable<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) in your collection class and return an new instance of your iterator class from the `iterator()` method.

You should probably also implement higher collection interfaces, such as [`List<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any class can implement [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html).  Then, you return another class (as mentioned, often an inner one) that implements `Iterator` from `iterator`.

In most cases it is fairly straight-forward.  However, we can help if you have specific questions.  Note that `remove` is optional.

You may also want to implement [`ListIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html), which is intended specifically for lists.

Comment: I thought `Iterable` was just for the foreach loop

Comment: @HunterMcMillen, nope.  That's a common use case, but not the only one.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen - It's useful for that, certainly. But it has other uses as well.

Comment: Implementing ListIterator is considerably more complex. It's main value is in supporting bidirectional movement (and possible the optional `set` method). If that's not needed then I'd recommend sticking with `Iterable`.

Comment: @TedHopp, more complex certainly.  But is a list, so it's not a case of a square peg and a round hole; it's not *that* difficult.  I agree he should consider whether it's worth it.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen - Just because something is a list doesn't mean it should always have a ListIterator; there may be practical reasons to not support it. For instance, if OP's list is a singly linked list, implementing ListIterator is an open invitation to inefficiency because going backwards is an O(n) operation.

Comment: @Ted, I agree.  I assumed it was doubly-linked.  If it's single, that's a strong reason not to implement it.